# Crawling a long list of URLs with Scrapy, it finishes prematurely

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm doing a small research project, and I have a file with 2.5 millions of URLs, taken from Wikipedia dump. Spider code looks like this:

```py
import re
import scrapy

class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wiki"

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('../urls.txt') as f:
            for url in f:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        results = re.findall(PATTERN, response.body)
        for res in results:
            yield dict(
                res=res.decode('ascii'),
            )
```

Since URLs point to different domains, I wanted to have multiple requests to different domains simultaneously, but make a long pause between querying same domain again. So here are some of my settings:

```py
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 10
AJAXCRAWL_ENABLED = True
SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue'
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1000
REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE = 40
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 1
```

First it starts crawling with decent speed, but slows down after a couple of minutes:

```
2022-03-21 22:22:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1641 pages (at 548 pages/min), scraped 1901 items (at 702 items/min)
...
2022-03-21 22:43:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2334 pages (at 7 pages/min), scraped 3099 items (at 60 items/min)
```

And then stops completely, while not scraping even 1% of my URLS:

```
2022-03-21 22:44:43 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is it some settings I'm missing, or `start_requests` is not a correct place to feed requests into the crawler, for such use case?

Comment: What are you DOING with these results?  Are you accumulating a list of millions of dictionaries?  It's possible you are simply running out of memory.

Comment: I run it like `scrapy crawl wiki -o wiki.jl`, I beleive it should just append new line to file and continue, without accumulating something in memory. And it finishes normally, even dumping some scraping stats. So does not look like OOM to me.